# Solr 5.5.0 response is not proper

Tags: solr

solr mysql response is not proper
am using solr 5.5.0
this is my codes

```
<dataconfig>
    <datasource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" user="user" password="password"/>
    <document name="user">
    <entity name="user" query="select * from user">
    <field column="id" name="id"/>
    <field column="name" name="name"/>
    </entity>
    </document>
</dataconfig>
```

**schema.xml schema file**
        ,I am retrieving id and name indexed

```
    <field column="name" name="name" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field column="id" indexed="true" stored="true" name="id"/>
```

**MY output**

```
        "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 5,
        "params": {
        "q": "*:*",
        "indent": "true",
        "wt": "json",
        "_": "1456634392166"
        }
        },
        "response": {
        "numFound": 38,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
        {
        "id": "1",
        "_version_": 1527391572777238500
        }
```

`numFound` and `id` is correct `name` is not coming.

Comment: dataconfig>
    <datasource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" user="user" password="password"/>
    <document name="user">
    <entity name="user" query="select * from user">
    <field column="id" name="id"/>
    <field column="name" name="name"/>
    </entity>
    </document>
</dataconfig>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response returns the fields which are specified in the `fl` parameter.

Just append `fl=id,name` to your query.

Comment: f1=id,name   am not getting name "docs": [
      {
        "id": "1"
      },

Comment: Use fl (FL in small capitals) not  f1 (f one)

Comment: http://ipaddress:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?q=*%3A*&fl=id%2Cname&wt=json&indent=true

Comment: http://ipaddress:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?q=*%3A*&FL=id%2Cname&wt=json&indent=true

Comment: am new on solr i tried both am not getting the name

Comment: Then it's a problem of the data importer.

Comment: how to find the dataimport error . am getting this while  dataimport Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 38 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
Requests: 1, Fetched: 38, Skipped: 0, Processed: 38

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the importer.

Comment: You could create a complete test document via the admin interface to be 100% sure that the query is correct.

Comment: Thanks for helping :)