# Solr query only returns Id only

Tags: solr

I want to retrieve the name from the user but it returns the id only.

I am using solr5.5.0

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource  driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://server:3306/dbname"  user="user" password="pwd"/>

 <document name="user"> 
    <entity name="user"   query="select id,name from user">
       <field column="id" name="id"/>
       <field column="name" name="name"/>       
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>

<field  type="int"  indexed="true" stored="true"  name="id" />
<field multiValued="true" name="name"  type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

output
response:

```
{
"numFound": 38,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "_version_": 1527443171669180400
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "_version_": 1527443171672326100
  },
```

Comment: <field  type="int"  indexed="true" stored="true"  name="id" />
<field multiValued="true"   name="name"  type="text"  indexed="true" stored="true" />


<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr 5.5.0 mysql response is not proper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679927/solr-5-5-0-mysql-response-is-not-proper)